# new Date() возвращает NaN в Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, дата, safari

Перепробовала вообще все, что гугл выдавал - не работает: приведение к числу (parseInt(), Number()) или строке, через  setDate().
Сталкивались ли вы с таким и как лечили?

Моя функция обрабатывает дату в шаблоне VUE, приходящую из JSON

```html
<p>{{ getFormattedDate(document.date.date) }}</p>
```

```js
getFormattedDate: function (value, separator = '.') {
      if (!value) {
        return false;
      }

      let date = new Date(value);
      date.setDate(date.getDate());

      let day = date.getDate() < 9 ? `0${ date.getDate()}` : date.getDate();
      let mount = date.getMonth() < 9 ? `0${ date.getMonth() + 1 }` : date.getMonth() + 1;
      let year = date.getFullYear();

      return `${ day }${ separator }${ mount }${ separator }${ year }`;
    }
```

Comment: пример первого параметра покажите

Comment: 1. Параметром для `new Date` может быть timestamp, как в вашем случае. 2. Получить текущий timestamp можно как `+new Date`